# ElasticSearch Failing to Authenticate LDAP Host

Tags: ssl, certificate, elasticsearch

I have the below ElasticSearch configuration, where ES is configured to trust both the root CA and the issuing CA. (The LDAP1 realm contains the relevant information.)

```
xpack:
  security:
    enabled: true
    transport:
      ssl:
        enabled: true
        verification_mode: certificate
        keystore:
          path: /etc/elasticsearch/security/elastic-certificates.p12
        truststore:
          path: /etc/elasticsearch/security/elastic-certificates.p12
    http:
      ssl:
        enabled: true
        verification_mode: certificate
        certificate_authorities: ["/etc/elasticsearch/security/rootCA.pem", "/etc/elasticsearch/security/issuingCA.pem"]
        certificate: "/etc/elasticsearch/security/elstcweb1.company.com.cer"
        key: "/etc/elasticsearch/security/elstcweb1.company.com.key"
    authc:
      realms:
        native:
          type: native
          order: 0
        ldap1:
          type: ldap
          order: 1
          url: "ldaps://ldapserver.company.com:636"
          bind_dn: "user"
          user_search:
            base_dn: "redacted"
          group_search:
            base_dn: "redacted"
          ssl:
            certificate_authorities: ["/etc/elasticsearch/security/rootCA.cer", "/etc/elasticsearch/security/issuingCA.cer"]
```

However, when attempting to log in to the service, I am receiving the below LDAP exception.

```
[es-prod-1] Authentication to realm ldap1 failed - authenticate failed (Caused by LDAPException(resultCode=91 (connect error), errorMessage='An error occurred while attempting to connect to server ldapserver.company.com:636:  java.io.IOException: LDAPException(resultCode=91 (connect error), errorMessage='Unable to verify an attempt to to establish a secure connection to 'ldapserver.company.com:636' because an unexpected error was encountered during validation processing:  SSLPeerUnverifiedException(message='peer not authenticated', trace='getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:440)
```

I was initially informed that root and issuing CA certificates were those that were used to sign the LDAP servers certificate. However, when troubleshooting using `openssl verify`, I received the following exception, which led me to believe that may not be the case:

```
openssl verify -verbose -CAfile /etc/elasticsearch/security/[rootCA.cer,issuingCA.cer,combinedRootIssuingCA.cer] ldap.pem
ldap.pem: C = US, L = REDACTED, O = REDACTED, OU = DSS, CN = ldapserver.company.com, emailAddress = REDACTED
error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

I obtained the LDAP server's certificate (`ldap.pem` in the above example) via `openssl s_client`:

```
openssl s_client -connect ldapserver.company.com:636 2>/dev/null </dev/null |  sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > ldap.pem
```

Given the above, is my assessment that the certificate of the LDAP server was not signed by the root/issuing CA correct? Or was the `s_client` method not the appropriate way to obtain the LDAP server's CA?

**EDIT:** Full error message with manually inserted line breaks:

```
[2019-01-21T15:03:22,268][WARN ][o.e.x.s.a.AuthenticationService] [es-prod-1] Authentication to realm ldap1 failed - authenticate failed (Caused by LDAPException(resultCode=91 (connect error), errorMessage='An error occurred while attempting to connect to server ldapserver.company.com:636:  java.io.IOException: LDAPException(resultCode=91 (connect error), errorMessage='Unable to verify an attempt to to establish a secure connection to 'ldapserver.company.com:636' because an unexpected error was encountered during validation processing:  SSLPeerUnverifiedException(message='peer not authenticated', trace='getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:440) 
 verifySSLSocket(HostNameSSLSocketVerifier.java:113) 
 <init>(LDAPConnectionInternals.java:166)  connect(LDAPConnection.java:860) 
 connect(LDAPConnection.java:760) 
 connect(LDAPConnection.java:710) 
 <init>(LDAPConnection.java:534) 
 getConnection(SingleServerSet.java:229) 
 getConnection(ServerSet.java:98) 
 getConnection(FailoverServerSet.java:545) 
 createConnection(LDAPConnectionPool.java:1205) 
 createConnection(LDAPConnectionPool.java:1178) 
 getConnection(LDAPConnectionPool.java:1706) 
 doPrivileged(AccessController.java:native) 
 privilegedConnect(LdapUtils.java:75) 
 searchForEntry(LdapUtils.java:258) 
 searchForEntry(LdapUtils.java:210) 
 findUser(LdapUserSearchSessionFactory.java:225) 
 getSessionWithPool(LdapUserSearchSessionFactory.java:78) 
 session(PoolingSessionFactory.java:101) 
 lambda$doAuthenticate$1(LdapRealm.java:125) 
 doRun(LdapRealm.java:283) 
 doRun(ThreadContext.java:723) 
 run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) 
 runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) 
 run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) 
 run(Thread.java:748)', revision=24201)')'))
```

Comment: Did you really get an error message that was almost 600 characters long in a single line?   If not, please [edit] your question and insert line breaks where they actually occurred.

Comment: The error message as reported in the logs was 1719 characters in one line. However, it looks like the logs indicate line breaks with the `/` character. I've added the full message at the bottom with those line-breaks included.

Answer (score 0):

There ended up being a third CA that needed to be trusted. This CA signed their LDAP server's VIP cert.